# How to match numbers that have the format 1,234,567

Tags: python, regex

I need help finding a regex rule that should search in a large string/text and  match numbers that have the format: 12,345,678 or 1,234,567 or 12,345 or 1,234.

for example:
for 12,345,678 it should match 12,345,678 and not 345,678 or 45,678 or anything similar

I looked in: [Regex help needed to match numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31321640/regex-help-needed-to-match-numbers)
but the answers either match 1 in 1,23,456 (should not at all because 1,23,456 is not a number) or match 23,456 in 12,23,456 (should not match at all)

In creating a regex rule to match the correct format number, I tried first creating the rule of what it should not match(i.e., not 1,23,456), then I tried creating the rule of what it should match. The last rule I created matches in most cases, but not in all.

```
number_regex1 = re.compile(r'''     # should not, but matches 12,233,57 = 12,233             
                          ((\d\d(?=[\s.,]\d\d\d))((?<=\d\d)[\s.,]\d\d\d)([\s.,]\d\d\d)+)| # matches 12,345,678
                          ((\d(?=[\s.,]\d\d\d))((?<=\d)([\s.,]\d\d\d))([\s.,]\d\d\d)+)| # matches 1,234,567
                          (((?<!\d[\s.,])(?<!\d)(?<!\d\d[\s.,])(?<!\d\d\d[\s.,])\d\d(?=[\s.,]\d\d\d))((?<=\d\d)[\s.,]\d\d\d))| # matches 12,345
                          (((?<!\d[\s.,])(?<!\d)(?<!\d\d[\s.,])(?<!\d\d\d[\s.,])\d(?![\s.,]\d\d)(?=[\s.,]\d\d\d))((?<=\d)[\s.,]\d\d\d))| # matches 1,234''', re.VERBOSE)
```

I want that when I do

```
mo = number_regex1.search('12,345,67')
```

nothing is matched, as 12,345,67 is not a number

Comment: Please format this all properly

Comment: So you want to see if an entire string is a valid number? Then just do `int(my_str)` in a try except. Regex will look for a number inside of a string.  Or are you trying to find a number in a large string? Please add several inputs and desired outputs.

Comment: You probably need `(?<!\d,)(?<!\d)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?!,?\d)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/D35Rfp/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the rule works nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
re.findall(r'(?<!\d,)(?<!\d)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?!,?\d)', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7rvxXA/1) and the regex graph:

[image]

**Details**

- `(?<!\d,)` - no digit and a comma is allowed immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?<!\d)` - no digit is allowed immediately to the left of the current location
- `\d{1,3}` - 1 to 3 digits
- `(?:,\d{3})*` - 0 or more repetitions of `,` and 3 digits sequence
- `(?!,?\d)` - no optional `,` and then a digit is allowed immediately to the right of the current location.

Note the two lookbehinds are required - `(?<!\d,)(?<!\d)` - as lookbehinds must be fixed-width (`(?<!\d,|\d)` won't work).

Comment: Nice. But, I do not understand why the **?**  after the **,** in the last parentheses `(?!,?\d)` is so important( it avoids matching bad formats).

Comment: @puskini33 The `(?!,?\d)` is acting as a number boundary preventing the match if there is a `,<digit>` or just a digit. `(?!,?\d)` is the same as `(?!,\d)(?!\d)`.

Comment: When searching through texts it is indeed handy not to be too strict with your commas